# Concurrent Calls to Self-hosted ServiceStack Service

Tags: servicestack

My ServiceHost class is inheriting from AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase in order to be able to process concurrent HTTP calls. However, my service is still handling concurrent API calls in a serial way. My service is self-hosted in a win32 console Application. What did I miss here? code snipit from the initialization & configure functions is below.

```
 public ServicesHost() : base("MiTrendz Backend Services", 500, typeof(KeywordsManager).Assembly) { }
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            //Signal advanced web browsers what HTTP Methods you accept
            base.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                GlobalResponseHeaders =
                {
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
                },
                WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://www.......",
                DebugMode = true,
            });
            container.Register(new MyService());


            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
            //This method scans the assembly for validators
            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(My Validator).Assembly);

        }
```